# fabric-java-sdk: where to change the chaincode

Tags: java, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

#### Foreword

Hi, I am new to stackoverflow. If there is any place that is not clear, please point it out. Thank you!

#### Question

I just started to study [hyperledger-fabric](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release/). As a Java programmer, I choose to use the [fabric-java-sdk](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-java).

After I can run the test case [End2endIT.java](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-java/blob/master/src/test/java/org/hyperledger/fabric/sdkintegration/End2endIT.java), I want to change the `chaincode`. I just find the [example_cc.go](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-java/tree/master/src/test/fixture/sdkintegration/gocc/sample1/src/github.com/example_cc) at `fabric-sdk-java/src/test/fixture/sdkintegration/gocc/sample1/src/github.com/example_cc/example_cc.go` . However, after I changed the chaincode, it did't work. Even after I deleted this code, the test case can still run.

Therefore, I guess I found a wrong place. Can anyone tell me where to change the `chaincode`? Thx!

#### Additional

1. The code to load chaincode

   ```
   if (isFooChain) {
       // on foo chain install from directory.

       ////For GO language and serving just a single user, chaincodeSource is mostly likely the users GOPATH
       installProposalRequest.setChaincodeSourceLocation(new File(TEST_FIXTURES_PATH + "/sdkintegration/gocc/sample1"));
       //[output]: src/test/fixture/sdkintegration/gocc/sample1
       System.out.println(TEST_FIXTURES_PATH + "/sdkintegration/gocc/sample1");
   } else {
       // On bar chain install from an input stream.

       installProposalRequest.setChaincodeInputStream(Util.generateTarGzInputStream(
               (Paths.get(TEST_FIXTURES_PATH, "/sdkintegration/gocc/sample1", "src", CHAIN_CODE_PATH).toFile()),
               Paths.get("src", CHAIN_CODE_PATH).toString()));

   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the question in the end as I noticed the [fabric.sh](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-java/blob/master/src/test/fixture/sdkintegration/fabric.sh) in the [fabric-sdk-java](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-java).

- `./fabric.sh up` to force recreate the docker container
- `./fabric.sh clean` to clean the peers

The reason why I could run the invoke request without chaincode is that I didn't clean the volumns of peers.

And the source code as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#
# Copyright IBM Corp. All Rights Reserved.
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
#
# simple batch script making it easier to cleanup and start a relatively fresh fabric env.

if [ ! -e "docker-compose.yaml" ];then
  echo "docker-compose.yaml not found."
  exit 8
fi

ORG_HYPERLEDGER_FABRIC_SDKTEST_VERSION=${ORG_HYPERLEDGER_FABRIC_SDKTEST_VERSION:-}

function clean(){

  rm -rf /var/hyperledger/*

  if [ -e "/tmp/HFCSampletest.properties" ];then
    rm -f "/tmp/HFCSampletest.properties"
  fi

  lines=`docker ps -a | grep 'dev-peer' | wc -l`

  if [ "$lines" -gt 0 ]; then
    docker ps -a | grep 'dev-peer' | awk '{print $1}' | xargs docker rm -f
  fi

  lines=`docker images | grep 'dev-peer' | grep 'dev-peer' | wc -l`
  if [ "$lines" -gt 0 ]; then
    docker images | grep 'dev-peer' | awk '{print $1}' | xargs docker rmi -f
  fi

}

function up(){

  if [ "$ORG_HYPERLEDGER_FABRIC_SDKTEST_VERSION" == "1.0.0" ]; then
    docker-compose up --force-recreate ca0 ca1 peer1.org1.example.com peer1.org2.example.com ccenv
  else
    docker-compose up --force-recreate
fi

}

function down(){
  docker-compose down;
}

function stop (){
  docker-compose stop;
}

function start (){
  docker-compose start;
}


for opt in "$@"
do

    case "$opt" in
        up)
            up
            ;;
        down)
            down
            ;;
        stop)
            stop
            ;;
        start)
            start
            ;;
        clean)
            clean
            ;;
        restart)
            down
            clean
            up
            ;;

        *)
            echo $"Usage: $0 {up|down|start|stop|clean|restart}"
            exit 1

esac
done
```